# Blazor/ dotnet 5.0.0: Set selected value in InputSelect

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-5, placeholder, selected

I need to set the selected value in the dropdown as a placeholder. Since the update to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 it will not work anymore. The input field is just empty and no value is selected. It was working before the update.
Setting the selected attribute is not working too.

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="someValue" id="someValue" required>
    <option value="">some Text</option>
    @foreach (var someValue in someValues)
    {
        <option value="@someValue">@someValue</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that your `someValue` inside your Model allows to be nullable. Here you define

```html
<option value="">...
```

that your option value is null or a empty string. If you use string as your datatype then everything is fine. But if you use an object like the newly added support for `System.Guid` then this has to allow for nullable values.

For example:

```cs
public Guid? someValue { get; set; } = null;
```

Using `Guid.Empty` would be also possible if you use this

```html
<option value="@(System.Guid.Empty)">...
```

But that depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The code you present works fine in rc2.

Note: I made assumptions about the `EditForm` usage.

```
<EditForm EditContext="SomeContext">

    <InputSelect @bind-Value="someValue" id="someValue" required>
        <option value="">some Text</option>
        @foreach (var someValue in someValues)
        {
        <option value="@someValue">@someValue</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>

</EditForm>

@someValue

@code {
    IEnumerable<string> someValues = new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
    EditContext SomeContext { get; set; }
    string someValue;

    SomeModel someModel = new SomeModel();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SomeContext = new EditContext(someModel);
    }

    class SomeModel { }
}
```

However : You use "someValue" everywhere. I will need to see more of your code to find the error. If you paste this on the bottom of a junk/test projects index page this will work. The `EditForm` configuration/bindings maybe the issue.

Comment: Your code is working. 
Thank you for answering!
"some Text" is preselected when the page is loaded.